# Subtract values in a list from the first value (Python)

Tags: python, list, indexing, methods, subtraction

I have a list of ints and i want to go through every number of the list and subtract it from the first like how a calculator would do multiple input subtraction.

```
myList = [3,2,1,4,5]


def subtractionDifference(n):
  start = n[0]

  for num in n[1:]:
      difference = start - num
  return difference

print(subtrationDifference(myList))
```

this prints -2 and ideally it would print -9

Comment: Try to run it with pen and paper, and see if you really want to subtract `num` from `start` in each loop...

Comment: Why not just slice the list? ```mylist[0] - sum(mylist[1:])``` or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
myList = [3,2,1,4,5]

def subtractionDifference(n):
  difference = n[0]

  for num in n[1:]:
      difference = difference - num
  return difference

print(subtrationDifference(myList))
```